# HtAccess Rewrite Can't Find File

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I have a small web app that I'm in the process of deploying to a server. However, suddenly the htaccess file isn't working (not the index file, but when I go to a url such as `/login`). It keeps maintaining that the file doesn't exist, however, the file that it displays as "unfindable" definitely does exist. I checked the relative path `/home/sites/xxx.co.uk/public_html/index.php` displayed by the error with a `file_get_contents` and it shows the file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it, it was just something with my Hosting Provider. The site was being tested on a test url they provided (while the domain is registered) and they had a strange method of identifying your folder (needed `/home/sites` to be removed)